# How to consume console logs of Chrome DevTools or Firebug programatically?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

I need to save Firebug's or the Google Chrome *Console* panel's log. I tried `console.log()` to play with printing logs, but what I need is to programatically save these developer tools logs into files.

Comment: For what sources? Logs generated by websites? Logs generated by your extension?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code, make an effort, and we'll be happy to help you, but you can't ask us to do it for you.

Comment: @Xan, my terminal aim is to analyse the logs generated by extensions like NoScript, Ghostery, and Adblock Plus. One way is to do so by post-process the logs generated from the console process associated with browser 'firefox -console | grep 'Extension's specific logs messages''. I am wondering if there is any easy way to save the logs shown in console panel.

Comment: [Firebug Trace](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/FBTrace) extension is really useful to analyse the traces (even though it isn't programmatically consume the traces yet useful to analyse bugs in executing javascripts, etc). Traces could be exported to filesystem (after opening Firebug panels you could could click on firebug icon on the upper lift corner): Open Firebug Tracing > Tools > Save To File.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebug has an extension called [ConsoleExport](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Extensions#ConsoleExport), which does exactly that.
This extension exports the messages logged to Firebug's console in XML format. In the current released version 0.5b5 it only auto-exports to a server URL. Though, in the meantime [code landed already](https://github.com/firebug/consoleexport/commit/22bddbd9170788e09a88d33d357ab1a9fc84eb56) (see [issue 9](https://github.com/firebug/consoleexport/issues/9)) to auto-export to the file system, which will (hopefully) be released soon (see [issue 21](https://github.com/firebug/consoleexport/issues/21)).